# Magento Connect Manager is Broken post Migration

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, file-upload, magento-connect-manager

Magento Connect Manager shows an error "Unable to save settings" when changing settings, and "No file was uploaded" when trying to install an uploaded package from a tgz file.

I'm using Magento CE 1.8.1 on PHP 5.3.3

All permissions have been set to 777.